# Prove that $b^{r+s} = b^{r}b^{s}$ if r and s are rational. Specific detail with regards to proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Prove that $b^{r+s} = b^{r}b^{s}$ if r and s are rational. Also $b > 1, b \in \mathbb{R}$

My question has to do with a specific aspect of this proof. I'm taking the question from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin.

So say we have defined $r = \frac{p}{q}$ and $s = \frac{m}{n}$, where $p, q, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

To prove this statement I will end up showing that both sides are equivalent to a particular expression. That expression being: $$b^{np}b^{mq}$$

In proving from the side where $(b^{r+s})^{nq}$, I arrive at the following expression: $$b^{pn + mq}$$

In all of the solutions that I have seen, they make the jump from $$b^{pn + mq} = b^{pn} b^{mq}$$

Of course this is how the properties of exponents behave, but it is this exact property that I am trying to prove, so how is making that jump to the final step even possible?

Comment: Have your proven that $(b^a)^c=b^{ac}$ for rational exponents? Because you're using it, and you shouldn't if you haven't proven it. @DietrichBurde I feel that a natural middle ground would be positive real.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited my question. $b>1, b\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the exact property you are trying to prove. In the latter the exponents are integers; and it can be proven easily by induction (or almost by definition) if you prefer, as it is just counting $b$'s. That is, $b^{m+n}$ means to multiply $m+n$ instances of $b$; while $b^mb^n$ means to multiply $m$ instances of $b$ with $n$ instances of $b$ for a total of $m+n$ $b$'s.

Comment: I don't completely follow what you are alluding to, $r$ and $s$ are stated to be rationals and not integers. So how would I use the integer properties to arrive at the solution?

Comment: By doing exactly as you wrote in your question, you reduce the problem to the integer case.

Comment: Hmmm...now that you mention that and looking at the solution again that is very interesting. I never looked at it with that perspective. Thank you for the help.